# Symfony 3 | FOSUser Block registration if connected

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, registration

I'm using FOSUser and I would like to return an exception or simply block access to registration if user is already connected. When I'm connected, by url, I can still go to /register.

This is my access_control :

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I could override registration controller action and return an AccessDeniedException but I'm sure there is a better solution, with security.yml maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I have to use Voters to check user permissions.

This is doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

And there is great example here : http://henrik.bjrnskov.dk/symfony2-anonymous-users-access/

And this is what I have :

```
- { path: ^/register, role: IS_ANONYMOUS }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add this:

```
- { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

then use:

```
php bin/console fos:user:promote user_name ROLE_ADMIN
```

to add "user_name" to the ROLE_ADMIN, then other users will get an Access Denied message.

Comment: TY for your answer. But if I add : - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN } to security then anonymous user will not have access to registration. I want user to access this page when they are anonymously and to not access this page when they are logged.